# Why isn't it necessary to provide a parameter in this function?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm fairly new to Haskell and this week I found this particular function in a couple of lecture slides. I'm trying to understand why the following function doesn't need to include a parameter:

```
-- Return all final segments of the argument, longest first 
-- (horrible runtime complexity, used here for illustration purposes only)
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails = reverse . map reverse . inits . reverse
```

If I would call it like `tails "thisisastring"` then this would be a valid argument. Isn't it necessary to provide a parameter, for example `tails xs = ...`. All the other functions I seen before were in that fashion.

Comment: FYI, that's a *terribly inefficient* definition of `tails`. It would make at least somewhat more sense to define `inits` in terms of `tails`, although that wouldn't be great either. `tails`, implemented properly, is inherently much more efficient than `inits`: `O(n)` rather than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I already noted that it was from some lecture slides so the point was to illustrate some new concept. Efficiency doesn't play any role here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter is implicit. Or to put it differently, `reverse . map reverse . inits . reverse` evaluates to a function of type `[a] -> [[a]]`.

Consider a simpler example:

```
double_impl x = x * 2
double = double_impl
```

The type of `double` here is the same type as `double_impl`, i.e. it takes one parameter of typeclass `Num`:

```
main = do 
  print $ double_impl 5
  print $ double 5

-- Out: 10
-- Out: 10
```

Comment: I'm starting to understand it a little bit. I'm trying to determine why tails will result in [a] -> [[a]]. Starting with reverse (at the end because of .), it needs [a] -> [a], after that inits need [a] -> [[a]] which is valid because the output of reverse is [a]. After that I'm stuck since map needs a function (reverse again) but also [a] while [[a]] is given as output by inits. How does that work?

Comment: `map` doesn't *require* an `[a]`; because of currying, `map` is a function that takes an `a -> b` and returns a function of type `[a] -> [b]`. `map f list` is really two function applications; `map f` produces a function, and that function is applied to `list`. (Function application is left-associative, so `map f list` is equivalent to `(map f) list`.)

Answer (score 4):

This is called point-free style (where "point" is a mathematical term that basically means "argument" here).

Even `tails xs = ...` is just syntactic sugar for `tails = \xs -> ...`, so all you need to do to convince yourself that `tails` is a function is to recognize that

1. `reverse`, `map reverse`, and `inits` are all functions:

   - `map` is a higher-order function; it takes one function as an argument and returns another function.
   - `map reverse` is a function because `map` is applied to the function `reverse`.
2. The composition of two functions is another function (assume that the types match up so that we can focus on the result of each composition, instead of verify that each composition type-checks.)

Thus

- `reverse . map reverse` is a function,
- so `reverse . map reverse . inits` is a function,
- and `reverse . map reverse . inits . reverse` is a function.

Since `tails` is assigned the value of `reverse . map reverse . inits . reverse`, `tails` itself is also a function.

Answer (score 2):

We can see that `tails` is a function, by checking it's type.

To compute its type, we begin by writing down the types of all the intermediate functions in the composition. Note that we use new type variables for each ocurrence of a function.

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
inits :: [b] -> [[b]]
map :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]
```

Now we have `map reverse` has type `[[e]] -> [[e]]` since we get `c=d=[e]` for some type `e` from comparing the expressions

```
reverse :: c -> d  -- for some c and d
reverse :: [e] -> [e] -- for some e
```

Hence the last two intermediates have types

```
map reverse :: [[e]] -> [[e]]
reverse :: [f] -> [f]
```

Now we start trying to match up types. Let me emphasize first that obviously THESE ARE NOT REAL TYPES! (sorry for the all caps, but I don't want anyone to miss that.)

```
inits . reverse :: [a] -*- [a] = [b] -*> [[b]]
-- I'm using a -*- b -*> c to denote the type a -> c obtained by
-- composing a function of type a -> b with one of type b -> c.
-- The *s are to break the double dashes up,
-- so they aren't parsed as a comment.
-- Anyway, looking at this type, we see
-- we must have [a] = [b], so a = b
-- we can rewrite the type of inits . reverse as
inits . reverse :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Then for the next composition:

```
map reverse . inits . reverse :: [a] -*- [[a]] = [[e]] -*> [[e]]
-- again, we have [[a]] = [[e]], so e = a, and we have
map reverse . inits . reverse :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Finally, we have

```
reverse . map reverse . inits . reverse :: [a] -*- [[a]] = [f] -*> [f]
-- This time we have [[a]] = [f], so we must have f = [a], so the type
-- of the final composition is
tails = reverse . map reverse . inits . reverse :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

Since `tails` has the type `[a] -> [[a]]`, it must be a function that accepts a list of `a`s as it's argument and returns a list of lists of `a`s.